# Is it possible to force a link to actually become a hyperlink in SMS?

Tags: sms

Is there a way to easily send a link to someone that uses a non-standard domain extension `.me`. When I send it, my phone and their phone doesn't auto-linkify it because it doesn't use a common extension. Whenever I've sent links with `.com` before they automatically become links, but using my `.me` domain it appears it gets ignored, even when it has the full `http://` in front of it. Is it possible to identify that part of a message as a hyperlink/URL when sending the message, so it gets shown as a link to the person on the receiving end?

Answer (score 4):

The "linkification" is actually handled by the SMS application on the device, not by anything within the message. If their device is not changing it to a link, then the device is not parsing the links correctly for all top level domains. There is nothing you can do about it really. The only thing that I could think of around this is to use some link shorter that will show as a clickable link and send those, but that is a lot more work because now you need to generate the shortened link first.